# Accessing "many to many" relationship class using ArcGIS Identify?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, relationship-class, many-to-many

I am trying to create a many to many relationship class in ArcGIS 10.0. When Identifying the features though, I don´t see the associated table values.

Here is the Class schema:

Destination Table name = "TypeDef" ( a table containing a list of Type definitions)

```
TypeID* | Typ_Name
```

Origin Table name = "Points" ( A point geometry)

```
ElementID* | Element_Name
```

Association Table name ="ElementTypes" (join table with ElementIDs and TypeIDs)

```
ElementID* | TypeID*
```

My ManyToMany Relationship class is defined as:

```
SourceTable
PK: ElementID
FK: ElementID

DestinationTable
PK: TypID
FK: TypeID
```

However, when I use the Identify Tool on a point, only the Relationship name is shown and not the attributes. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Many2Many]

Answer (score 3):

Make sure all the Keys have the same data type. One of the keys was a double instead of text....but strangely this wasn´t identified by ArcGIS.